# How to make color part of a text for UI in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I change the color of part of a text?
I'm trying to make it so the text says "`Don't have an account? Register now!`" but I want to add color to the `Register now!` part. How can I do this if possible?

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`RichText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html):

```
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: "Don't have an account? ",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 40),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(text: ' Register now!', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

[image: Result]