# How do change the color of subtext value in flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I change the color of a subtext value in flutter. I have the following code and would like "sign in" and "sign up" to be in a different color

Thanks for your help

```
child: Text(
 (isSignInScreenState)
   ? "don't have an account? sign up"
   : "already have an account? sign in",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 18.0,
  ),
 ),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I color part of a text for UI in dart/flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778185/how-can-i-color-part-of-a-text-for-ui-in-dart-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RichText` and `TextSpan`:

```dart
String question = isSignInScreenState ? "don't have an account? " : "already have an account? ";
String signText = isSignInScreenState ? "sign up" : "sign in";

// ...

RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: question,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: signText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.red)),
    ],
  ),
),
```